# append to div IE9

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to append a Session variable to a div using jquery in IE9, although it seems not to be working. I can see the values if i use a response.write to the page, but when I go to append it doesn't take. Can someone shed a little light. Thanks.

```
        <div id="uploadedFiles"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           var x = @Session["FilesList"];
           $("#uploadedFiles").append('<span>Files</span>');
           $("#uploadedFiles").append('<p>' + @Session["FilesList"] + '</p>);
        </script>
```

Comment: And what exactly is `@Session["FilesList"]`, if it's a string you have a syntax error when writing it to the `x` variable, as you're missing quotes.

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML that comes out of that piece of code? It might shed more light on if and what kind of syntactical error it produces.